# Java, Factory Pattern for dynamic style classes?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a library/android module that provides certain custom ui classes. (PanelView, GridView, TextView ...) All of these classes are stylable. Styles are parsed from text files into JSONObjects, organized in a StyleManager and from there retrieved and turned into a Styling object. The first idea would be something like

```
public class PanelView_Styling{
    public static PanelView_Styling createFromJSON(JSONObject data){...}
}
```

But then I cannot use an Interface for Stylings that includes a creation method. (No static methods in interface pre Java 8.)
The next alternative would be a factory

```
public class StylingFactory{
    public static Styling createStylingFromJSON(int stylingType, JSONObject data){
    switch( stylingType ){
        case 0: 
            /* get and validate attributes from data */
            /* return null or new Styling instance filled with the attributes */ 
        break; 
    }
}
```

The int typecheck is just an example. It could be a class reference, or enum, or even an attribute of the styling data or something different.
But the main problem with that approach is, that I cannot add new Stylings without changing the factory. When I use the ui module inside another one I will at some point have `ExtendedPanelView` and `ExtendedPanelView_Styling`. The Styling will have its own parameter validation logic, so I cannot just use reflection and copy everything from JSON into the Styling.

I think an abstract factory might be a solution. I would have a concrete factory for the basic ui elements and stylings already in the lib. Then I would have to implement a custom factory in each module that has additional ui elements and stylings. Then combine instances of the concrete factories under one instance and somehow figure out which factory is able to create stylings of which type. (Maybe just call each of them until one returns an object, or they all failed).
But this seems rather complicated. Is there a simpler, more straightforward approach to this problem?

Comment: I would have thought of a **Decorator Pattern**, just hope you don't ask me how here.

Comment: That does not sound too bad actually. A little bit simpler than managing a list of `FactoryImpl` instances. I could have a BaseFactory in the lib and a decorator Factory in the specific app. All creation of base classes is delegated and all new classes are handled by the decorator. It would be slightly easier to manage the base factory as an inner factory than managing the "injection" of specific factories into the base factory.

Comment: Your factory is a so-called concrete (or simple) factory as there is no polymorphism involved. You can make a factory that is more dynamic, with reflection (instantiating a class by its name, which requires mapping the `stylingType` to a Java type). A more pragmatic approach might be to use the switch/case, and if you find that you're spending a lot of time modifying your factory for new implementations (or you want users to be able to have "plug-ins" for styling), then go to the dynamic version with reflection. *Perfect is the enemy of good.*

Comment: That's exactly what I've been doing for now. I have the factory in the lib and fill it with mappings `<String, Class>`. Then I parse the JSON and create Styling instances via reflection. The Styling interface guarantees presence of `createFromJSON()`. For custom components I just add custom mappings and that's it. But it needs reflection, hence it's less generic. But you are right about perfect and good! Still it a bit unsatisfactory. But even mapping StylingCreator  instances (if no reflection) would feel cleaner than polymorphic factories e.g.